# How to use simpleBar in a project with vue 3

Tags: vue.js, frontend, simplebar

I want to make a glowing scroll bar, but since Mozilla does not support scroll customization, I decided to use simpleBar - it works great on vue 2 but does not work on vue 3, how can I use it on a vue 3 project?

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property '_c' of undefined
at Proxy.__vue_render__ (simplebar-vue.esm.js?8d3b:39)
at renderComponentRoot (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:1168)
at componentEffect (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:5214)
at reactiveEffect (reactivity.esm-bundler.js?a1e9:42)
at effect (reactivity.esm-bundler.js?a1e9:17)
at setupRenderEffect (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:5167)
at mountComponent (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:5126)
at processComponent (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:5084)
at patch (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:4690)
at mountChildren (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:4874)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<template>
  <div data-simplebar></div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
  import { defineComponent} from 'vue'

  import 'simplebar-vue/dist/simplebar.min.css'
  import 'simplebar-vue/dist/simplebar-vue.js'

  export default defineComponent ({
    name: 'test',
  })
</script>
```

It worked for me.